# Iterate through a file lines in python

Tags: python

I have a file which have some names listed line by line.

```
gparasha-macOS:python_scripting gparasha$ cat topology_list.txt 
First-Topology
Third-topology
Second-Topology
```

Now I am trying to iterate through these contents, but I am unable to do so.

```
file = open('topology_list.txt','r')
print file.readlines()
for i in file.readlines():
    print "Entered For\n"
    print i

topology_list = file.readlines()
print topology_list
```

file.readlines() prints the lines of the files as a list. 
So I am getting this:

```
 ['First-Topology\n', 'Third-topology\n', 'Second-Topology\n']
```

However, When i iterate through this list, I am unable to do so.

Also, when I assign it to a variable 'topology_list' as in the penultimate line and print it. It gives me an empty list.

```
[]
```

So I have two questions.

What is wrong with my approach?
How to accomplish this?

Comment: `file.readlines()` reads all the lines. That means after the first call, the file pointer is at the end of the file which causes the second and third calls to `file.readlines()` to return empty.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The simplest:

```
with open('topology_list.txt') as topo_file:
    for line in topo_file:
        print line,  # The comma to suppress the extra new line char
```

Yes, you can iterate through the file handle, no need to call `readlines()`. This way, on large files, you don't have to read all the lines (that's what `readlines()` does) at once.

Note that the `line` variable will contain the trailing new line character, e.g. *"this is a line\n"*

Comment: Good solve, and thank you for the explanation of that phantom new line character!

Comment: why doesn't your print statement have parenthesis??

Comment: That because when I answered this question, I was using Python 2.7

Comment: Comma trick's clever! `line.strip()` is perhaps clearer – and `rstrip()` if you want to keep existing breaks. For those curious why that comma works: `print()` appends a line break if provided 1 arg, and a space if >1.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code like this:

```
file = open('topology_list.txt','r')
topology_list = file.readlines()
print topology_list
for i in topology_list:
    print "Entered For\n"
    print i
print topology_list
```

When you call `file.readlines()` the file pointer will reach the end of the file. For further calls of the same, the return value will be an empty list.