# python-reading a text file

Tags: python, text-parsing

I have a ".txt" file from which I was parsing and printing lines by two different ways, but instead of getting two outputs, I am only getting a single output of printed lines.

```
**pi_digits.txt contains**:--
3.141692653
  897932384
  264338327
```

Below is the code:

```
with open("pi_digits.txt") as file_object:
    #contents = file_object.read()
    #print(contents)
    for line in file_object:
        print(line.rstrip()) #deletes the whitespace of \n at the end of every string of file_object
    lines = file_object.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line.rstrip())`
```

output is only:

```
**
3.141692653
  897932384
  264338327
**
```

occurring 1 time but I think it should occur two times.

Comment: could you format it a little? there should be a code insert button that looks like <>, it's hard to help debug like this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate through a file lines in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124206/iterate-through-a-file-lines-in-python)

Comment: alternatively, if you want to loop over lines twice, you can update the loop condition to something like `for line in lines * 2:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not occur twice.  By the time you get to the end of your first loop:

```
    for line in file_object:
        print(line.rstrip()) #deletes the whitespace of \n at the end of every string of file_object
```

You have read through the whole file.  The file_object is positioned at the end of the file.  Thus, this line reads nothing:

```
    lines = file_object.readlines()
```

If you really want to go through it twice, do the `readlines` call first, and have both `for` loops use the list instead of the file iterator.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, it seems I have a weak fundamental of file parsing.

Comment: A file always has a "current position".  Every time you read, you advance the "current position".  When you reach the end, it stays at the end until you close the file or use `.seek` to change the position.