# How do I divide the content of a txt file by /2 in Python without encountering 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10'?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that can divide with /2 from a txt file python

So in this code op will read the content of txt

```py
with open("python/file/t.txt") as txt:
    op = txt.read()
   
    def div():
        divide = int(op)/2
        print(divide)
div()
```

But it is showing me a error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10'`

My t.txt file has 1 to 10 arranged vertically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate through a file lines in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124206/iterate-through-a-file-lines-in-python)

Comment: your input is newline delimited. Use a for loop over `op.split("\n")`

Answer (score 3):

When you call `read()` you are getting back the entire contents of the file. The text of the numbers **and** the newline characters. To process each number (one per line) you would want to split `op` on the newline character `"\n"`.

Something like:

```py
with open("in.txt", "r") as file_in:
    for row in file_in.read().split("\n"):
        print(int(row) / 2)
```

Note that `split()` would also be valid as the default behavior is `split()` to do so on whitespace including line breaks and tabs.

However, this is such a common thing python allows one to simplify this to:

```py
with open("in.txt", "r") as file_in:
    for row in file_in:
        print(int(row) / 2)
```

Either will give you back:

```
0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
3.0
3.5
4.0
4.5
5.0
```

**Addendum:**

Per the OP, the use of `readlines()` also fits the bill here and I will pull their comment into this answer for clarity.

```py
with open("in.txt") as file_in:
    for row in file_in.readlines():
        print(int(row) / 2)
```

Comment: Thx well I figured it out by myself                                                                                                           
 `with open("python/file/t.txt") as txt:
    op = txt.readlines()
    save = []
    for line in op:
        div = int(line)/2
        print(div)
`

Comment: `readlines()` does much the same and is a fine alternative. You might not need the `save = []` though

Comment: I have a question  from where does this \n come from it is a text file and i have stored numbers vertically does it have a relation with ascii

Comment: the newline character(s) `"\n"` and in windows `"\r\n"` and handled in python as simply `"\n"` are control characters that can appear in strings indicating that when displayed a newline should be rendered. They are the content in your file that allows your numbers to render "vertically". Tab characters `"\t"`  are a second example. They do appear in the ASCII encoding but they are also appear in (almost?) every other encoding in some form.