# How can I find duplicate values in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have various blocks of code and I need to view duplicate values. The values I'm looking for are in quotes so I need to see if 41 appears more than once somewhere etc.

Is it possible to do this?

```
'41','34','31','40','42','41'='IE041' 
'30','35','32','33'= 'IE042'
'20','28','29','26','27'='IE051' 
'2-','2&','12','10','19'='IE052'
'21','22','23','25'='IE053' 
'00','02','03','04'='IE061'
'1-','11','16','15'='IE062' 
'14','18','17','13'='IE063'
```

Comment: seems offtopic maybe you want to ask at https://superuser.com/

Comment: @RandRandom Notepad++ is arguably a tool used primarily by programmers. With plugins it can be a fully featured IDE.

Comment: `keyboard is arguably a tool used primarily by programmers.` - so can I ask question related to cleaning my keyboard? @TylerH

Comment: @RandRandom No, pretty much anyone who uses a computer uses a keyboard. See the word "primarily" in my comment. People generally don't use Notepad++ unless they are developers. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311935/are-text-editor-regex-questions-off-topic/311943#311943 and, more recently, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401968/how-should-i-have-flagged-this-vim-centric-question (about Vim, a tool in the same exact category as Notepad++)

Comment: Could you show what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

- Select `41`,
- hit CTRL+M,
- Choose 'Mark all' ,

After that your should see something like:

[image]

EDIT: "just to please @RandRandom"

```
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='mark', description='highlight a search argument')
parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('search', nargs='+', help='Supply search argument')
args = parser.parse_args()

input = str(args.filename[0])
search = args.search[0]
print("Filename:"+ input)
print("Search:" + search)

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-do-i-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124206/iterate-through-a-file-lines-in-python

with open(input) as topo_file:
    for line in topo_file:
        line = line.replace('\n','')
        line = line.replace(search,bcolors.OKCYAN + search + bcolors.ENDC)
        print(line,)
```

test output:

[image]

Comment: and now show how to do it in eg. python to make it something about programming :)

Comment: @RandRandom: Why would you do it in python?Question is about searching values in Notepad++.

Comment: @Toto - "programming" != searching in notepad++ - stackoverflow is about asking quesiton related to programming https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpqLc.png - and searching text in a texteditor no matter how that text editor is called and who may or may not primarily use it is irrelevant, question has nothing to do with programming

Comment: @RandRandom: Have you looked at the links provided by @ TylerH in comments? Questions about Notepad++ are valid in SO.

Comment: @Toto - sure did, I whole heartedly disagree that this statement `a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development` applies to searching in a text editor